# Drupal ecommerce theme no correctly viewed

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, themes, e-commerce

Im quite new to drupal, At the moment ive been trying to install a commerce theme but i dont get the correct appearance of it

the original theme 
[image]

how it looks in my localhost

[image]

i have alreay installed drupal commerce, panels, ctoold, views etc... can sosmebody tell me what has gone wrong and how do i get the original look of the theme

Comment: any drupal experts out there!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lot of things you need to do after installing the theme.

After installing new theme you should do the following:

1. Change default logo to your site logo.
2. Check what menu items are displayed and manage them in your structure>>menus
3. Add slider images by checking where to add the images (Read your theme readme.txt)
4. Add content so as to display in appropriate areas.
5. Add Products to your site.
6. Configure home page link.
7. Configure your categories / popular categories tags blocks.
8. Configure special offers block. May be you need to create a view with block display.
9. Place search block in appropriate region.

I am listing few and you can figure out rest if anything is not at its position.

Note: Generally the theme provides you basic regions, templates, css and icons structure, and you have to manage your site content so as to get the look and feel.